# Is it allowed to use Cambria and Cambria Math fonts in a book?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

What about commercial use of Cambria and Cambria Math OTF fonts? I mean whether a publishing house could take these fonts to print my book? As far as I know, the Cambria fonts are included with Windows 7.

Comment: Printing should be allowed but you should be careful. Some font licences require that you make your pdfs read-only. Also there may be restrictions about embedding your font files. Finally, I suspect that your publisher may only edit your files if they have a font licence too. (Your publisher may want to change parts of the text and/or add text in the preamble.)

Comment: This question is not Tex-related.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You can buy Cambria fonts and use them like any other fonts.